# Remove tipTip tool tip

Tags: jquery, tiptip

See http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin

`$(".someClass").tipTip();`  used to add special tool tip to html elements.

How can I remove,such a tiptip tool tip created?

Comment: Is it creating `title` attribute?

Comment: From reading the documentation it looks like there isn't a method of removing the tooltip via the plugin - which is very poor. Your best bet is to look through the code and find the events it attaches to and manually unbind them.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - I just used a custom namespace and added a `destroy` function to make it a little easier to undo. The events weren't name-spaced before so the OP could have accidentally removed necessary events.

Answer (score 2):

I've rewritten some parts of the plugin to make it *much* easier to work with. However, there is *a lot* more that could be done to clean up the code.

Basically, I just used a [custom event namespace](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names) (`.tip`) which allowed me to re-structure the plugin and create a destroy method that simply calls `$(this).off('.tip');`.

The new plugin code is a little too long to post here so take a look at this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/VaXHWE5N

I've also created a working fiddle with the updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/hQmvk/3/

Comment: What if you wanted to turn it on again?

Comment: @BenAluan - good point, there was a small typo in my original update which made it throw an error if you tried to reapply tipTip. I've just updated the pastebin link and the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Use custom attribute for tooltip text (do not use 'title' or data-attributes) and set attribute value to empty string.

For example,

```
    // add tooltip
    $(".test-element").tipTip({ attribute: 'tooltip-content' });
    ...

    // clear tooltip
    $(".test-element").attr('tooltip-content', '')
```